# How to perform several http requests with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, design-patterns

I need to perform several http requests. I have an array of urls, when each request completes the `JSON object` is pushed into an array. When all the requests finish, the `JSON object` is sent to the client with the newly constructed `Array`. If I was doing this client side, I would use something like `jQuery`'s Deferred object. Is there another approach using `node.js` without having to `import jQuery's Deferred object`? Doesn't seem like event emitter would be used to handle this. Or would it? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, event emitter can handle this. One solution I could think of is emit an event after every finished request, like event:processed_url_count. Then have a listener like event:total_url_count, which will trigger the sending to the client with the array containing all the requests.

Comment: I was actually thinking along the lines of this, but thought it would be messy. I'll try it.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you allow multiple connections in **Node.js** first

```
require('http').globalAgent.maxSockets = 1000
```

This snippet allows your Node.js server to accept 1000 http requests per client.

---

There are many **flow control** libraries in Node.js.

Famous ones are [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) and [step](https://github.com/creationix/step).

Personally I prefer `async`, because It has functions similar to [underscore](http://underscorejs.org) or [lodash](http://lodash.com) but async versions of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution.

This class extends EventEmitter. What it does is for every asynchronous request response, we emit the count of finished asynchronous requests and store the body of the response.

```
var UrlHandler, events, request, urlHandler,
  __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty,
  __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; };

events = require("events");
request = require("request");

UrlHandler = (function(_super) {
  __extends(UrlHandler, _super);

  function UrlHandler() {
    return UrlHandler.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }

  UrlHandler.prototype.getUrls = function(urls) {
    var processedUrls, url, urlhandler, _i, _len, _results;
    processedUrls = 0;
    urlhandler = this;
    urlhandler.urlResponse = [];
    _results = [];
    for (_i = 0, _len = urls.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
      url = urls[_i];
      _results.push(request({
        uri: url
      }, function(error, response, body) {
        urlhandler.urlResponse.push(response);
        processedUrls++;
        return urlhandler.emit("processed:" + processedUrls);
      }));
    }
    return _results;
  };

  return UrlHandler;

})(events.EventEmitter);

urlHandler = new UrlHandler();

module.exports = {
  urlHandler: urlHandler
};
```

Then in your main app, we put the listener as `'processed:' + urls.length` so it will trigger once it's done with all asynchronous requests.

```
urls = ['http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739605/how-to-perform-several-http-requests-with-node-js', 'http://stackoverflow.com'];

UrlHandler.getUrls(urls);
UrlHandler.once("processed:" + urls.length, function() {
  return res.json(UrlHandler.urlResponse);
});
```